# Controlling a top-level LabVIEW VI in a (unit/acceptance) test using events

Tags: events, tdd, labview, acceptance-testing

I'm trying to use in LabVIEW, a technique described in "Growing Object-Oreinted Software, Guided by Tests", by Steve Freeman and Nat Pryce (Addison-Wesley 2010). (Ch. 4 Kick-starting the test-driven cycle. Examples in the book are in Java, using JUnit 4, jMock2, Hamcrest and WindowLicker).

The top-level VI will have an event loop and a lot of controls and several indicators. In the test situation, I need to programmatically control the buttons and fields, as well as read the data of the indicators.

It seems I need to generate events that mimics buttons being pressed. I also need references to the indicators.

How can this be done? Googling has so far only found how to react on events within the same VI.

Comment: One possibility is to open a VI reference for the main VI, use Property Node to get a Panel reference from it, then the Controls[] reference, use indexing to get one of the controls, cast it to the correct instance (e.g. Button), then invoke it's methods at will. Not sure if that is *the* standard way of doing it, but it does work. Shorter and less error-prone would be to have the main VI expose references to all it's front panel objects somehwo (publish to a queue or global variable or so).

Comment: Worth trying. I guess i must start the main GUI with an asynchronous call by reference, and then use invoke nodes to execise the panel controls.